# How do I handle Daylight Savings when working with database through JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, timezone

My MySQL server is configured to use UTC (default-time-zone = "00:00" in my.cnf) and I added "serverTimezone=UTC" in the data source URL.

As I understand, this means 2 things:

1. The MySQL server stores any date/time data in the UTC zone;
2. The JDBC knows it.

Suppose I have some Dao class with a LocalDateTime field:

```
class MyDataDao {
    public LocalDateTime theDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-10T10:00:00");
    // some other fields ...
}
```

And then I want to insert MyDataDao into the database:

```
m_jdbc.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_ADDMYDATA, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        //... some other fields ...

        // the date time field
        ps.setObject(3, myData.getTheDate());
        return ps;
    }
}, genKey);
```

Now that here come the questions:

I queried the database in the CLI, it was "2020-01-10 **09:00:00**".

I am in central Europe, so my "standard" timezone is "UTC+1". It seemed that the JDBC automatically adjusted "theDate" from "UTC+1" to "UTC".

**However, I know it is in Daylight Savings Time now, so the practical timezone is actually "UTC+2". Unfortunately, JDBC did not take this into account.**

The questions are:

1. Is all my understanding above correct?
2. How can I make the JDBC take the DST into account?

*(I tried TimeZone.setRawOffset(...) but it did not help. I know I can manually shift the "theDate" field before sending it to the JDBC, but I guess it is definitely not the best practice)*

Thank you!

Comment: What is your timezone ?

Comment: For CET, the 10th of January is UTC+1, not UTC+2, however it is weird that it is applying timezone transformations at all: that shouldn't happen with a `LocalDateTime` on a (non-timezone) `TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If I have understood correctly, MySQL is special (compared to other RDBMSs) here: A `timestamp` is always “*with* time zone”. If you want it without time zone (very seldom recommended), you need to use the `datetime` datatype instead.

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is poorly designed and long outdated. If you need a class for a time zone, go for `ZoneId` from java.time (where also `LocalDateTime` comes from).

Comment: What is your datatype in MySQL? For a `datetime` column I would not have expected that any time zone be applied when storing. For a `timestamp` column store an `OffsetDateTime` with offset 0 (use `ZoneOffset.UTC`), and you should be able to control exactly what is stored.

Comment: @NAIT hi, like I wrote in the post, my timezone is UTC+1 in "standard" zone. It is UTC+2 in Summer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hi Mark, truly sorry for the bad test values! I was testing it yesterday (24/10/2019) which was still in DST. The test value "2020-01-10" was just a random value that I fabricated. I didn't expect JDBC to determine whether to do transformation based on the value. I guess it is based on the wall clock of the host OS.

Comment: Actually when talking about timezone it makes more sense to talk about timezoneId such as `Europe/Paris, Africa/Ndjamena, Pacific/Fiji...` and not timezoneOffset such as 'UTC+2, UTC +1...`

Comment: As I mentioned bellow when you use your session timezone (which is what you actually do when you query your database). If for instance you live in Paris the Europe/Paris timezone is used by default and it's not always UTC+2 or UTC+1 it really depends on the date you're retreiving form the database, if the date is in janury for instance UTC+1 will be used but if the date in august then UTC+2 will be used, do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @OleV.V.hi, thank you for the replies. The column type is, unfortunately, datetime, due to the range limitation of timestamp. The thing is that I thought the transformation isn't done by MySQL server, but by clients, like JDBC. Now the symptom is the transformation is automatically carried out, and would be correct if it were not in DST.

Comment: @NAIT I see your point. You mean the database or the JDBC will do automatic time transformation based on both the OS's timezone and the DST rules. That's why we should avoid talking about the exact time offset.

Comment: Yes Excatly @zhou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the timezone that will be applied will always depend on the Daylight saving used at the moment refred to by your date and not on the current Dayight saving, it's always easier with an example :

Let's say I created a document in my database with a column creation date containing the value `01/01/2019-12:00:00 UTC`.

- When I query the document the 02/02/2019 (at this time the used time
  zone offset in paris is UTC+1) then the document returned will have
  the following value "01/01/2019-13:00:00 Paris".
- When I query the
  same document the `01/08/2019` (at this time the used time zone
  offset in paris is UTC+2) then will also return 01/01/2019-13:00:00
  Paris.

So the applied timezone offset depends on your timezone and the daylight saving applied the moment refered to by your date object.

Comment: ... Oooh, this time I got your point really. You mean the automatic time transformation is not based on the time the query is performed but based on the actual time value to be queried! Therefore, my test value is "2020-01-10" will never trigger DST transformation no matter I test it in Summer or in Winter. That's a big surprise to me. (btw, I'm a beginner to database) I will test it again this evening with a different test value representing a Summer time. Thank you very much!

Comment: It helped me a lot!